# Using asterisks as delimiter, format the captured data with <li></li>

Tags: regex, angular

I am faced with the problem that I have a string that is in this format

```
"*word words words. *word word word. *anotherword anotherword."
```

that I need to format into a li tag to be displayed like this

- word words words
- word word word
- anotherword anotherword.

i've tried stuff like

```
^((?!\*).)*$
```

but this does not do as required.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could split on an asterix `*` and trim / filter the results

Answer (score 1):

Use split and iterate over it, like below -

```
str = "*word words words. *word word word. *anotherword anotherword.".split('*').slice(1);


<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let word of str'>{{word}}</li>
</ul>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6t1ds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Split on this string will create an empty first element.

Comment: @x15 yes even I was thinking about that, anyways we can add `slice` method after split.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with regex this is just a little bit javascript:

ts-file:

```
substrings: string = mystring.split('*');
```

in html:

```
<li *ngFor="let string of substrings">{{ string }}</li>
```

Comment: syntax error => `..split(*);` should be `...split('*');`

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=\*).*?(?=\.)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBPXan/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
tempStr = "*word words words. *word word word. *anotherword anotherword.".split('*');
  str = []

  constructor() {
    this.tempStr.map(element=>{
       if(element != ""){
      this.str.push(element);
    }
    })
  }
```

Given solutions did not check for empty, directly slicing first element. If * character is not there at start position, slice would remove first element in array , where you will loose data.